# sort a Laravel collection on the behalf of four conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, laravel-5

i have a comanies table like this in mysql.it has 3 columns. is_verified,is_platinum,platinum_start_date, end_date.
[image: table collumns]

on the frontend, the data is showing in paginate format so that now I want to get the companies list sorted in only one variable.
just to show companies first verified then non verified then platinum etc

1. All Platinium and verified companies
2. All Platinium
3. All verified companies
4. All no verified and no platinum user.

I have tried by "orderBy","Sorting" etc but by using individual variable

> $companies = DeveloperCompanies::where('is_approved', '=',
>   1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(9);

[here is a table format](https://www.dropbox.com/s/64dwr8bgyjnbwao/developer_companies.sql?dl=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `orderBy` four times for each column

```
$companies = DeveloperCompanies::where('is_approved', '=', 1)
->orderBy('is_verified', 'desc')
->orderBy('is_platinium', 'desc')
->orderBy('platinium_start_date', 'desc')
->orderBy('platinium_end_date', 'desc')
->paginate(9);
```

Comment: great it's working but sometimes its platinum but start_date and end_date is expired means that that will be  13-07-207-12-08-2017
so it's expired is there any check that I can apply just on this value if it's not valid date range it still the platinum company

Comment: currently, i am using helper function in for each to check if it's valid then show otherwise skip but i think its time taking process check on every value.
just if its not in date skip this

Comment: use where again for your new condition like this `DeveloperCompanies::where('is_approved', '=', 1)->where('column','>=','value')...`

Comment: yes, I want to apply this condition on just for those columns who have value is_platinum=1?

Comment: no you don't get my point ok its ok i just want to ignore the company who have is_platinum=1 but its start,end_date not valid means that it has been expired so that i want to skip this don't come first in this condition ?

Comment: sorry , just busy right now , I had read your last comment but I cannot get your point

Comment: ok no problem i will let you know if i face any problem i got the logic behind this thanks again